# Starting Android SensorEventListener On Button Click

Tags: android, sensors, android-sensors

I want Sensor listener to start getting information from the sensor on button click.But right now whenever my activity starts, the sensor event listener starts invoking sensor. In short I want to control when should sensor event listener starts invoking sensor and when it should stop listening from the sensor from a button. How can I do that?

My code is below :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    final Button posture=(Button)findViewById(R.id.posture_test);
    final Button uploaded=(Button)findViewById(R.id.upload);
    final Timer start_rec = new Timer();
    final android.os.Handler han=new android.os.Handler();
    final TextView timer= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timertxt);

    startService(new Intent(this,GPS_Location.class));          //starting the service to get location of user every 1 minute



    posture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            posture.setEnabled(false);
            new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    timer.setText("Time Left: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000+" Sec");
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    timer.setText("Test Completed");

                }
            }.start();

            han.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.d("STOPPED","...");
                        posture.setText("STOP");
                        uploaded.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        posture.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        sensorManager.unregisterListener(gyroListener);
                        //obj.getLocation();

                    }
                },60000);

        }
    });

    uploaded.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Uri uri=Uri.parse("http://192.168.43.125:8080");
            //Intent server=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
            //startActivity(server);
            Intent posture=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Tapping_Test.class);
            startActivity(posture);

        }
    });

    sensorManager=(SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensor=sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

    txtX=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textX);
    txtY=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textY);
    txtZ=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textZ);

}


public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    sensorManager.registerListener(gyroListener,sensor,sensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
}

public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(gyroListener);
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    finish();
}

public SensorEventListener gyroListener=new SensorEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        float x =event.values[0];
        float y =event.values[1];
        float z =event.values[2];

        txtX.setText("X: "+(int)x+" m/s2");
        txtY.setText("Y: "+(int)y+" m/s2");
        txtZ.setText("Z: "+(int)z+" m/s2");

        //Log.d("writing"," to csv"+event.values[0]);

        //writing to a csv file...
        try {
            writeToCsv(Float.toString(event.values[0]),Float.toString(event.values[1]),Float.toString(event.values[2]));

            //Log.d("writing"," to csv"+event.values[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }
};
```